# Unequal circles with plain HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I created bunch of circles with plain HTML and CSS, but it seems to me that not all of them are equal. To be honest, some of them look more like ellipses to me. Is there something wrong with my eyesight or there is some brower's limitation that I'm unaware of?

Here is the code that I used to reproduce the problem, as well as the image of the result (Chrome used for it).

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 150ms border linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  content: '';
}

.circle:hover::after {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

[image]

**Update: None of the answers actually solved the issue for me. Issue was browser related and I cannot reproduce it any longer.**

Comment: If you want perfect circles set `border-radius: 50%;` instead

Comment: @Brian that changed nothing for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: it's too small to be truly existing and visible, for me it looks like an optical illusion (and what's the point of having a `whitesmoke` circle on a `whitesmoke` background ?)

Comment: @MisterJojo it's pretty visible for me in a project that I used it.

Comment: reset the zoom in the browser - ctrl + 0 in chrome

Comment: @radovix I edited my answer according to your question. It should be working on all browsers without a problem.

Comment: how can you see your whitesmoke border circle on a whitesmoke background ?

Answer (score 2):

I changed `border-radius` to 50% and it seems to have fixed the problem on Chrome.

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 150ms border linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle1::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  content: '';
}

.circle1:hover::after {
  border-color: brown;
}
.circle2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 150ms border linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  content: '';
}

.circle2:hover::after {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
Original:<br />
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<br />
Fixed:<br />
<div class="circle2"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it must be something browser related then because that doesn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome v84.0.4147.125

Comment: I am on a chromebook and it looks like a circle on my computer.

Comment: Looks normal on Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful trick for creating equal circles and squares only by using CSS.
You set the `height: 0` and by setting the `width` and `padding-bottom` to the same dimensions you create a square that is also responsive if you use percentage instead of pixels. To create a circle you add a `border-radius: 100%` and you are set.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 150ms border linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  content: '';
}

.circle:hover::after {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by zooming the browser. Try to reset the zoom setting - `ctrl + 0` in chrome.

If you do want your circle to look round even when zoomed - you can use scaling. Usually, the larger the rendered item, the smoother the circle appears. You can create a circle with doubled size, and then scale it down:

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: brown;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  content: '';
}

.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  content: '';
}

.circle:hover::after {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a more simple and accurate way to approach it.

```css
.circle {
  background: brown;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  border: 3px solid brown;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is related to browser but the issue are hardly visible and when looked extremely closely

```
border-radius=50%;
```

should do the work